# Deleting duplicates from matrix

Tags: matrix

I have a 4x4 symmetric matrix that is obtained by solving some equations. I tried deleting duplicates with `DeleteDuplicates`, but that's not working with nested lists (elements of those lists that are the same).

So I have this

$$\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
  a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} \\
 \end{pmatrix}\to a_{nm}=a_{mn}\to 
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} \\
  0 & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} \\
  0 & 0 & a_{33} & a_{34} \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & a_{44} \\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

I'd like to be able to remove lower triangle of a matrix but only if they are the same. How to do that?

Comment: I noticed the `UpperTriangularize` function, which is what I need, it's just that I would like to be sure first if the matrix in question is symmetric. Should I make an If statement?

Comment: You can use `SymmetricMatrixQ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `mat` be your matrix:

```
func[mat_?SymmetricMatrixQ] := UpperTriangularize[mat];
func[mat_?(Not@SymmetricMatrixQ[#] &)] := mat;
```

If the matrix is symmetric the above will convert to upper triangular matrix including diagonal,else it will return original matrix, e.g.

```
m = {{a, b, c}, {b, d, e}, {c, e, f}};
m//MatrixForm
func[m]//MatrixForm
```

yields:

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) That does the trick :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this applies specifically to the OPs situation, but I thought I'd contribute just in case it's useful.  As mentioned in the comments, using `UpperTriangularize` with a conditional statement to check for symmetry is the appropriate route; however if the matrix elements are, for example, coordinates, then SymmetricMatrixQ won't recognize the matrix as symmetric.  A circuitous route to a 4x4 matrix of x,y coordinates:

```
m1 =  RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 4}];
m2 =  RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {4, 4}];
sm1 = m1 + Transpose[m1];
sm2 = m2 + Transpose[m2];
MapThread[Riffle[#1, #2] &, {sm1, sm2}];
sm3 = Partition[#, 2] & /@ %;
MatrixForm[sm3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`SymmetricMatrixQ[sm3]` returns False, but `sm3 == Tranpose[sm3]` returns True.  Additionally, `UpperTriangularize` doesn't like this matrix, so I make my own function:

```
newUpperTriangularize[x_] := UpperTriangularize[x /. {_, _} -> 1]*x;
newUpperTriangularize[sm3] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]